# how to get query result in JSON format from hive send results on AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: database, amazon-s3, hive

some query result output wants in JSON format, the query run in the hive, and to post the result on AWS s3.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in many ways.
You can use python to format result to JSON and send anywhere(may be this is better fit for your 'send results to AWS' purpose).
Alternately you can use the to_json UDFs' from Brickhouse[link](http://github.com/klout/brickhouse). If you convert your results to a named_struct and arrange columns as you want, it will interpret it as a JSON map, and output accordingly.
  `SELECT to_json( named_struct( "field1", field1,"field2", field2,"field3", field3 )) FROM mytable;`
The to_json will also interpret arrays and maps.